# how upload image & text input to same Row to google sheets

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I'm creating a google script webapp that will upload 10 photos long with comments about each photo , these info will be inserted to google sheet when pressing upload on the webapp
so I was able to upload each photo to the correct location in the spreadsheet but due lack of HTML knowledge I'm not able to grab the comments , also trying to show some notification/ progress so I'm able to tell that the process is completed . See my both Code & HTML below also here is a link of the target google sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r8vt9cMLvJ68AI6xu51sodkL6_j6tP_Y86cXEJOrvuQ/edit?usp=sharing

index.HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
   


  </head>
  <body>

<input name="file" id="files" type="file" multiple>
<label for="fname">Location </label>
 <input type="text" id="comment1" name="Location">
<label for="message">Notes </label>
<textarea name="message"id="note1"  style="width:200px; height:50px;">  </textarea> 
<br>
<br>
<input name="file" id="files" type="file" multiple>
<label for="fname">Location </label>
 <input type="text" id="comment2" name="Location">
<label for="message">Notes </label>
<textarea name="message" id="note2"  style="width:200px; height:50px;">  </textarea> 
<br>
<br>
<input name="file" id="files" type="file" multiple>
<label for="fname">Location </label>
 <input type="text" id="comment3" name="Location">
<label for="message">Notes </label>
<textarea name="message" id="note3" style="width:200px; height:50px;">  </textarea> 
<br>
<br>
<input name="file" id="files" type="file" multiple>
<label for="fname">Location </label>
 <input type="text" id="comment4" name="Location">
<label for="message">Notes </label>
<textarea name="message"id="note4"  style="width:200px; height:50px;">  </textarea> 
<br>
<br>
<input name="file" id="files" type="file" multiple>
<label for="fname">Location </label>
 <input type="text" id="comment5" name="Location">
<label for="message">Notes </label>
<textarea name="message" id="note5" style="width:200px; height:50px;">  </textarea> 
<br>
<br>
<input name="file" id="files" type="file" multiple>
<label for="fname">Location </label>
 <input type="text" id="comment6" name="Location">
<label for="message">Notes </label>
<textarea name="message" id="note6" style="width:200px; height:50px;">  </textarea> 
<br>
<br>
<input name="file" id="files" type="file" multiple>
<label for="fname">Location </label>
 <input type="text" id="comment7" name="Location">
<label for="message">Notes </label>
<textarea name="message" id="note7"  style="width:200px; height:50px;">  </textarea> 
<br>
<br>
<input name="file" id="files" type="file" multiple>
<label for="fname">Location </label>
 <input type="text" id="comment8" name="Location">
<label for="message">Notes </label>
<textarea name="message" id="note8" style="width:200px; height:50px;">  </textarea> 
<br>
<br>
<input name="file" id="files" type="file" multiple>
<label for="fname">Location </label>
 <input type="text" id="comment9" name="Location">
<label for="message">Notes </label>
<textarea name="message" id="note9" style="width:200px; height:50px;">  </textarea> 
<br>
<br>
<input name="file" id="files" type="file" multiple>
<label for="fname">Location </label>
 <input type="text" id="comment10" name="Location">
<label for="message">Notes </label>
<textarea name="message"id="note10"  style="width:200px; height:50px;">  </textarea> 
<br>
<br>
 
 <br>
 <input type='button' value='Upload' onclick='getFiles()'>
<script>
function getFiles() {
 // const f = document.getElementById('files');
  const fAll= document.querySelectorAll("#files");
  var commentList= ["comment1","comment2","comment3","comment4","comment5","comment6","comment7","comment8","comment9","comment10"];
  for (var i = 0; i < commentList.length; i++) { 
 var comment = document.getElementById(commentList[i]);
  
  }
   const noteList= ["note1","note2","note3","note4","note5","note6","note7","note8","note9","note10"];
  console.log(comment)
 fAll.forEach(function(f){
 [...f.files].forEach((file, i) => {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = (e) => {
      const data = e.target.result.split(",");
      const obj = {fileName: f.files[i].name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]};
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((id) => {
        console.log(id);
      }).saveFile(obj,comment);
    }
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
})



}
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

CODE.GS:

```
        function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function saveFile(obj,comment) {
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(obj.data), obj.mimeType, obj.fileName);
 var file=DriveApp.createFile(blob);
 var fileId= file.getId()
  //return fileId



  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK,DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);


        var fileUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+fileId;
  Logger.log(fileUrl);

 //var url=/* Google sheet URL */;
 var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
 var ws= ss.getSheetByName("Photos Report");
var newurls = '=image("'+fileUrl+'",2)';
     ws.appendRow([null,newurls, new Date(),comment]);

     return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);  

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to make users upload 10 images and input 10 comments and 10 notes, and you want to save the images to Google Drive and put the images, the URL of images, comments and notes to Google Spreadsheet.

### Modification points:

- In your script, `google.script.run` is run every loop.
- `comment` is one object.

  - In this case, in your `google.script.run`, one `comment` object is used.
- `noteList` is not used.
- When you want to use `querySelectorAll`, in your HTML, I think that all values can be retrieve with it.
- When all values are retrieved in Javascript side and they are sent to Google Apps Script side by one call, I thought it will reduce the process cost.
- At `saveFile` in Google Apps Script side, in your case, the value is returned with `google.script.run`. So `return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);` is not required. You can use `return "Success";`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### HTML&Javascript side:

Please modify your `<script>,,,</script>` as follows.

```
<script>
  function getFiles() {
    const files = document.querySelectorAll("#files");  // or document.querySelectorAll("input[type='file']")
    const comments = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
    const notes = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");
    const ar = [...files].map((f, i) => ({file: f.files[0], comment: comments[i].value, note: notes[i].value}));
    Promise.all(ar.map(({file, comment, note}, i) => {
      const fr = new FileReader();
      return new Promise(r => {
        if (file) {
          fr.onload = e => {
            const data = e.target.result.split(",");
            r({file: {fileName: file.name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]}, comment: comment, note: note});
          }
          fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else {
          r({file: null, comment: comment, note: note});
        }
      });
    }))
    .then(obj => {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => console.log(e)).saveFile(obj);
    });
  }
</script>
```

- In this modifieid script, from `upload 10 photos` in your question, one file is retrieved from each file input tag.

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please modify your `saveFile()` as follows.

```
function saveFile(obj) {
  const values = obj.map(({file, comment, note}) => {
    if (file) {
      var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(file.data), file.mimeType, file.fileName);
      var file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
      var fileId = file.getId();
      file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK,DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
      var fileUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+fileId;
      var newurls = '=image("'+fileUrl+'",2)';
      return ["", newurls, new Date(), note, comment];
    }
    return ["", "", new Date(), note, comment];
  });
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // or var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Photos Report");
  ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  return "Success";
}
```

- In your sample Spreadsheet, "Photo, Date, Notes" is set and "Comments" is not set. But, in your question, it seems that you want to put "Notes" and "Comments". So I added them.
- In your sample Spreadsheet, the script is the container-bound script. So I thought that `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` can be used instead of `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)`. But if you want to put the values to other Spreadsheet, please use `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)`.

### Note:

- **In your situation, the Web Apps is used. So when you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

### References:

- [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Tanaike , Thank you so much for your detailed answer , this worked perfectly except that everytime the code inputs 10 dates even if I uploaded only 2 images with notes and Comments .I believe because AR always return all 10 values whether its filled or not , any ideas on how to pick only the fields that has actual values ?.

Comment: @Aboude zoua Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about it. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand it. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply Tanaike , I was able to find a way a solution for my other issue . Thank you so much

Comment: @Aboude zoua Thank you for replying. I'm glad your new issue was resolved. Thank you, too.